# syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have checked this code many times and I cannot find a reason for this syntax error.

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
```

This is the code:

```
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require '00 hello/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "00 hello"
  spec.version       = 00 hello_VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["John Kirtley"]
  spec.email         = ["KirtleyJ16@gmail.com"]
  spec.description   = %q{TODO: Write a gem description}
  spec.summary       = %q{TODO: Write a gem summary}
  spec.homepage      = ""
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  spec.files         = `git ls-files`.split($/)
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.test_files    = spec.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.3"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake"
end
```

This is the modified code:

```
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require = 00hello_version



Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "00hello"
  spec.version       = "00hello:VERSION"
  spec.authors       = ["John Kirtley"]
  spec.email         = ["KirtleyJ16@gmail.com"]
  spec.description   = %q{TODO: Write a gem description}
  spec.summary       = %q{TODO: Write a gem summary}
  spec.homepage      = ""
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  spec.files         = `git ls-files`.split($/)
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) })
  spec.test_files    = spec.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.3"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake"
end
```

I changed the code a bit, and now the error I get is:

```
There was a SyntaxError while loading hello.gemspec:
/Users/John/$/hello.gemspec:4: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
/Users/John/$/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/John/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/John/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: You need to restructure this as a question.  Thanks, though, for using good formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You could comment out lines until you find it....

But the `00 hello_Version` looks dodgy to me.

Comment: I've tried changing the "_"to "/" , and ":". Still receive error.

Comment: The space is causing you the grief most probably. Can you rename your module to 00hello? or 00_hello ?

Comment: eliminated spaces, now I'm receiving "exepecting end_of_input error"  @peterept

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote your spec.version section.

```
spec.version = '00 hello_VERSION'
```

Comment: It was quoted previously, I removed them just to experiment. Still receiving error with them included. @muttonlamb

Comment: OK, which line is it crapping out on

Comment: no idea. I've commented out each line. I still receive the syntax error "exepecting end_of_input"

Comment: Perhaps there are more than one lines with errors then.  I think Jeff Dickey is also correct.  Try commenting out both of those lines.

Answer (score 0):

`spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }`

is missing an end paren